# com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.VersionMismatchException thrown when using JAX-WS to request a ws

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, soap-client

I'm tring to construct a client of a webservice using jax-ws, and this exception blocked me:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.VersionMismatchException: Couldn't create SOAP message. Expecting Envelope in namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, but got http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope 
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:167)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:278)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.isAlive(Unknown Source)
```

That is strange because my types are genereated by myEclipse, and nothing is modified. When I ran this webservice in SOAPUI with the same wsdl, it worked! but not in java (jax-ws). I think the wsdl is all right because the SOAPUI generated the envelope with the right namespace, but why the jax-ws insist to use the wrong one?

I use jdk6 and its internal jax-ws libraries.

I've searched for several days but nothing is found. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I have printed the soap request with handler, and it was exactely what it should be!!!

Comment: I have printed the soap request with handler, and it was exactely what it should be!!!
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it's the server proxy who send me another version of soap response...

Comment: how did you fix it? I have the same problem. Someone may help?