# How to handle on client side VersionMismatchException when changing wsdl is not possible

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, soap-client

I am trying to automate SOAP calls for my project.
I get below exception when I try to invoke a service.

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.VersionMismatchException: Couldn't create SOAP message. Expecting Envelope in namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, but got http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle.webservices.internal.impl.encoding.StreamDecoderImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.pingRequest(Unknown Source)
    at base.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:16)

Below is the code I am using

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args){

    ZcsAdminService zcsAdminService = new ZcsAdminService();
    ZcsAdminPortType abc ;
    abc = zcsAdminService.getZcsAdminServicePort();

    PingRequest params = new PingRequest();
    abc.pingRequest(params);

}}
```

I have no control over the wsdl so I can not change it to remove this mismatch.
Is there anyway I can handle it on client end?

Note: Went through this thread already [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188081/com-sun-xml-internal-ws-protocol-soap-versionmismatchexception-thrown-when-using?rq=1) but it does not provide any solution.